# Charging 2 12V batteries with a 19V 3.42A laptop charger

Tags: batteries, charger, laptop

I was wondering since the voltage of my laptop charge is too high to charge one battery, it occurred to me if it could be possible to make a parallel or series arrangement to get my 2 12V batteries charged.

Comment: Not recommended at all.

Comment: You didn't specify the 12V battery chemistry.

Comment: It will be possible to charge a 12V battery from a 19V *and some other stuff in the middle* but if you wanted to buy other stuff in the middle, you might as well go and buy a charger that plugs into the wall.

Comment: @replete The battery model is R-33CP for what I just checked is not made from sulfuric acid and lead but from absorbent glass mat (AGM so called) 12V-33Ah.

Comment: @immibis I must say I already tried put some 12V bulb in the middle but I don't know why it didn't work I connected the charger in serie with the bulb and then the battery I checked and re-checked it and the bulb never lighted up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO** you cannot charge your 12V AGM battery directly with a 19V Laptop power supply. You need a battery charger.

1. The laptop power supply IS NOT a battery charger, it is a fixed voltage SMPS power supply. The charger for the laptop batteries are inside the laptop.
2. AGM batteries are indeed Lead acid batteries. So your fully charged state is about 13.8 - 14.5V.
3. Putting two batteries in parallel does not change the voltage required to charge them it simply increases the current capability (increased Ah rating).
4. Putting two batteries in series may require up to 27.6V to fully charge (though you need a battery charger and NOT a power supply).

Buy a battery charger, or build a charger to use your 19V power supply.
If you are building a charger then you need three things:

1. Terminal voltage control
2. Current control
3. Float, trickle or On/Off charge control

There are several Chinese/Ebay charger modules (example - [XH-M603](https://www.ebay.com/itm/XH-M601-M609-12V-36V-6-60V-Battery-Charging-Control-Switch-Charger-Power-Supply/142755794920)) available that might suit your purpose. They take a wide range of input voltages.

Be aware if you intend to use your laptop 19V power supply that it is only capable of providing about 64W, so this limits your 12V charging to somewhat less than this. 
You might only be able to provide about 50W maximum to charge the batteries, giving about 3 - 3.5A of charge current as you approach fully charged.

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended at all. Voltage level is only the tip of the iceberg here. A charging circuit measures the current and voltage that goes into the battery, and charges the battery depending on its type in many different ways in different states of the battery. For example, when a battery is depleted, it is charged with a very small current to protect it. Then, it acts more like a current source until the battery is close to being full. Only after then, it can be said that the charger is a voltage source.

Some battery chargers take the temperature of the cells into consideration.

Even if it was not a terrible idea, say, we crash landed on an island and have to operate the radio, 19V source would only charge them up very very slightly, small enough to dismiss it as a charger.

Answer (score -1):

Ans is YES.. U HAVE to put two 12 v batteries in series
and step up(voltage boost) module (150 w ) make its out to 26v. I'm doing this from past. And I hav a battery full charge indicater. When it starts beep. I wll stop charging.

Answer (score -2):

It is easily possible if you locate the feedback point in the regulator and add a pot and series R to shunt Vfb in order to raise to 24V

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible. I have been doing it for years. I have a Jeep Wrangler that I only drive in summer time. The day before I plan to start using the car, I charge the battery overnight with a 19.2V DC, 2A laptop power supply fitted with battery clamps.
The Jeep is kept outdoors, so I don't have to worry too much about gas (hydrogen) produced as a result of charging. This is something to watch out for when charging any acid filled batteries indoors. Also, my car is old (1998) and does not have a lot of sensitive electronics. You may want to disconnect the battery from the car while charging it, to make sure the higher voltage from the charger does not damage any of the electronic components in your car.
Good luck.